# Windows Server 2008 R2 backup does not start as scheduled with no error messages

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to configure regular automated backups to a shared network drive using the Windows Server Backup console. When I backup manually, it works, however it does not run on its own as scheduled. I have made sure to enable run backup while not logged in. There are no error messages when it does not run according to schedule, it just skips to logging the next scheduled backup as the next day.

I have also tried using the wbadmin command line. My script is similar to the following:

wbadmin enable backup –addtarget:\backupshare\myshare –include: c:\ –user:DOMAIN\mylogin –password:mypassword –schedule:19:00 -systemState -quiet -allowDeleteOldBackups -

I have not received any errors with my script and the windows command line acknowledges that there is a scheduled backup to run. However, the backup does not run and when I check wbadmin get status at the time it is scheduled, it will tell me there is no back up running at the moment with no error codes.

I am not sure why my back ups will not run as scheduled as they will run manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to assume that you’re running it with heightened privileges and for running the task you’re using a Domain Admin account, I would suggest running the command manually from command line and add in this argument “get status > \task.log”